# Bitwise operation to get 1 if > 0 else 0

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I want to apply a bitwise operation on a value to turn it to 0 if the value is 0 or to turn it to 1 if it greater than zero.

Specifically I want a soultion in JavaScript, a way around `Number(Boolean(value))`

```
0 -> 0
1 -> 1
2 -> 1
3 -> 1
4 -> 1
...
```

can I achieve this with bitwise operations?
Arithmetic operations are fine, too.

Comment: Are arithmetic or logical operators allowed (e.g. `+` or `!`), or does it need to be strictly bitwise operators only ?

Comment: Artithmetic would be fine. 
Essentially I want a more eloquent way around Number(Boolean(value))

Comment: Good answers already, just for fun: `1-!x` should also do the trick

Comment: `Number(Boolean(x))` can be written as `+!!x` (unary operation)

Answer (score 4):

`!!x` is the idiomatic way of doing this, for an integral type (including boolean) `x`.

Comment: Not bitwise though (`!` is a logical operator).

Comment: Indeed, I assumed it was the "user doesn't quite know what they want" situation. And I'm too old to use ~ and ^.

Comment: You could be right - I've asked for clarification in the comments.

Comment: If used in JS for example a value of 3 will give me `true` i do not want a boolean, i want a Number

Comment: @Stremd: are you looking for a Javascript-specific solution ? If so then please tag your question accordingly.

Comment: @PaulR I edited the question, thanks. I wasn't really aware that there might be no differences between booleans and integers in other context

Comment: @Strernd it's more that other languages are *more strict* about the differences between booleans and integers. In Java, for example, `!x` is a compilation error if `x` is an `int`.

Comment: @Strernd "i want a Number" then do `!!x|0` now you have bitwise operation :)

Comment: @YuryTarabanko thanks, that's what I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

`x && 1` does it.

```
for(x=0; x<5; x++) {
   console.log(x & 1)
}
```

Writes:

```
0
1
1
1
1
```

This is a logical AND but Javascript's type rules appear to keep the result as a number.

---

But you should consider how many JS coders would instinctively understand this.

Preferring legibility to terseness, I would personally use the ternary operator:

```
x == 0 ? 0 : 1
```

... although the option you've asked to avoid is also highly legible:

```
Number(Boolean(x))
```

You seem to imply that this might be slower than the alternatives.

1. I see no reason why this would be slow. `Number` and `Boolean` are language built-ins that do very simple operations that we'd expect to be incredibly cheap
2. Premature optimisation is the root of all evil. You should only worry about this kind of micro-optimisation if your code is running unacceptably slowly. This operation would only have such an effect if it was running millions of times in a loop. If that was the case you could easily tell if another option was cheaper, just by trying it.

---

Note that your requirement:

> turn it to 0 if the value is 0 or to turn it to 1 if it greater than zero

... does not specify what you want to happen if `x` is negative. This answer allows you to tune accordingly.

Comment: I was just curious about if this method would be faster than using if or casting.

Comment: @Strernd both are stupidly fast. Don't optimise for speed unless you're experiencing problems with slowness and it results in a measurable improvement.